# Enum with arguments typescript

Tags: typescript

Swift can do this:

```
enum Barcode {
    case upc(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case qrCode(String)
}
```

Is there a way to include arguments in enum cases like that in Typescript? Thanks.

Comment: What Swift and Java refer to as an `enum`, other languages (including TypeScript) refer to as "discriminated-unions".

Comment: Which UPC specification are you using, btw? There isn't necessarily 4 modules in a UPC, so you should be specific about which spec you're using (e.g. UPC-A)

Comment: Ahhh yep that's what im looking for. Haha not doing anything with barcodes just found that example online. Thanks though!!

Answer (score 3):

What Swift and Java refer to as an `enum`, other languages (including TypeScript) [refer to as "union type"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type).

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

TypeScript offers many ways to skin a cat, but one idiomatic implementation in TypeScript equivalent is:

```
type Upc     = { S: number, L: number, M: number, R: number, E: number };
type QRCode  = { asText: string };
type Barcode = Upc | QRCode;
```

As TypeScript uses type-erasure there isn't any runtime information that *immediately* self-describes a `Barcode` object as either a `Upc` or a `QRCode`, so in order to discriminate between `Upc` and `QRCode` you'll need to write a type-guard function too:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

```
function isUpc( obj: Barcode ): obj is Upc {
    const whatIf = obj as Upc;
    return (
        typeof whatIf.S === 'number' &&
        typeof whatIf.L === 'number' &&
        typeof whatIf.M === 'number' &&
        typeof whatIf.R === 'number' &&
        typeof whatIf.E === 'number'
    );
}

function isQRCode( obj: Barcode ): obj is QRCode {
    const whatIf = obj as QRCode;
    return typeof whatIf.asText === 'string';
}
```

Used like so:

```
async function participateInGlobalTrade() {
    
    const barcode: Barcode = await readFromBarcodeScanner();
    if( isUpc( barcode ) ) {
        console.log( "UPC: " + barcode.S ); // <-- Using `.S` is okay here because TypeScript *knows* `barcode` is a `Upc` object.
    }
    else if( isQRCode( barcode ) ) {
        console.log( "QR Code: " + barcode.asText ); // <-- Using `.asText` is okay here because TypeScript *knows* `barcode` is a `QRCode` object.
    }
}
```